# Check with a servlet API if the client is continue listen on the request?

Tags: java, http, servlets, request

We have some long running `Servlet`'s request? We want stop this requests on the server if the client give up. Is it possible to detect via `Servlet` API whether the client has close the HTTP connection in the mean time ?

Answer (score 1):

Write a byte (space character?) to the response and flush. If it throws `IOException`, then you know enough.

By the way, a real background job (e.g. with `@Asynchronous` EJB), in combination with a kind of email notification with a specific link on finish, is likely a more user friendly approach.

Comment: This will corrupt the result. The result are not simple html files else different document files.

Comment: Then it's end of story as to using Servlet API. As alternative you may want to fire and listen on JavaScript polls and stop the processing when you no longer receives them.